ngx-editor-menu message error translation
Im using angular 16 with the ngx-editor and I cant finding anywhere a way to translate the error messages from the "link" option, I manage to work arround a solution but its not great because it has a delay with the original text and the custom error message I want, I will link the image of what I want to translate and the current workaround I have:
My Angular Code -
Component:
  editor: Editor = new Editor();
  toolbar: Toolbar = [
    ['bold', 'bullet_list', 'italic', 'strike', 'underline', 'link'],
  ];

HTML:
<ngx-editor [editor]="editor" [(ngModel)]="newCommunication.description" [disabled]="false"
                    [placeholder]="'Community.MessageText' | translate"></ngx-editor>
                <ngx-editor-menu [editor]="editor" [toolbar]="toolbar"> </ngx-editor-menu>

I want to translate:
URl form
This is a workaround I found using a JS script to capture all the clicks on the browser then search on the DOM for the specific tag and changes the innerHtml
function changeEditor() {
    if (!window.location.href.includes('Community')) {
        return;
    }

    var errors = document.querySelectorAll('.NgxEditor__HelpText.NgxEditor__HelpText--Error');
    errors.forEach(function(error) {
        var errorText = error.innerHTML;
        if (errorText === ' Please enter valid url. ') {
            error.innerHTML = 'Introduza um URL válido.';
        }
        else if (errorText === ' This is required ') {
            error.innerHTML = 'Este campo é obrigatório.';
        }`your text`
    }
    );
}


document.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev) {
    changeEditor();
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    changeEditor();
});


I'm confused, you say you are using angular yet the code provided does not resemble angular. Could you please clear this up?

This is a workaround I found that captures every click on the browser and checks the DOM elements then change the innerHTML, Im using angular but this is a JS script I created, I will identify better the question

For the URL validation there is no need for overriding the DOM. Simply use the locals configuration option:
NgxEditorModule.forRoot({
  locals: { enterValidUrl: 'Introduza um URL válido.' }
})

Source: https://sibiraj-s.github.io/ngx-editor/configuration/
This approach however does not work for the required validation, where the error message is hard coded. To fix this I would suggest to open a feature request on their GitHub, or contribute to the project by creating a pull request which implements this feature. In the meantime I'm afraid you will need to live with that workaround, at least for the required validation.
